# cant send an email on cakephp3

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I can't get cakephp3 to send emails. In cakephp2 I could do this no problem. I am using the latest WAMP, and cakephp3.3 on Windows 7. I tried to follow the directions but it looks like I am getting something basic wrong. Do I also need to configure Wamp as I checked the `php.ini`-development file but there is no smtp entry to change

> error- stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>   stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
>   (Unknown error)

```
controller

   public function singleTutorEmail(){


       $email = new Email();
       $email->transport('gmail3');

       $to='jjxxx@gmail.com';
       $subject='testing';
       $message='hello, dfsfsdfsdf sdfsdf';

       $email->from(['jjxxx@gmail.com' => 'test'])
                  ->to($to)
                  ->subject( $subject)                   
                  ->send($message);
}

in app.php

   'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
   'gmail3' => [
              'className' => 'Smtp',
             'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'jjxxx@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'client' => null,
           'context' => [
          'ssl' => [
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
             'allow_self_signed' => true
                 ]
             ]

        ],
    ],
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html
[Sending Mail using CakePHP 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375058/sending-mail-using-cakephp-3-0)

Comment: if you want to use gmail then the className should be `Smtp` and not `Mail`.

Comment: Ok but after that I get this new error ---stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:25 (Unknown error)

Comment: because 25 is not the standard smtp port. Try 465

Comment: yes i tried this 465 port and no difference. I will update what I have on the OP

Comment: did you told gmail you are trying to access to the email from your application? [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Comment: PS still see  'className' => 'Mail' in your code after the edit. Is it just a typo?

Comment: yes it is a typo, I have Smtp for classname

Comment: I used the same email for the cakephp2 version without an issue, what would I do in gmail for the cakephp3 version of sending emails ?

Comment: are tring in localhost or live server?

Comment: If you are using gmail as host , do you have correctly set Grant access to your account for less secure apps?

Comment: I can use the same email with my cakephp2 email setup  so what am I looking for the is stopping cakephp3 from working on my localhost?

Comment: I tried setting up wamp for emails but i still get the same error as above in OP, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396721/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-to-send-email-gmail-hotmail-or-so-f

Comment: I had another try at this email and I cant get it to work still as I have the same error in the OP when it sends an email. The openssl module is loaded in WAMP. Can anyone please help

Comment: It works if I add in these lines as I have php >5.6 . This is not in the docs of cakephp3  'context' => [
              'ssl' => [
              'verify_peer' => false,
              'verify_peer_name' => false,
                 'allow_self_signed' => true
                     ]
                 ]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when making an HTTPS request using Cake\Network\Http\Client

To resolve the problem, I had to download "cacert.pem" file from https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem

And then I updated php.ini by adding the following line:

```
openssl.cafile = <PATH_TO_CACERT_PEM>/cacert.pem
```

Don't forget to restart the web-server.
If the above thing doesn't make it work, try to update the OpenSSL library installed on your system.

I really hope this works for you too.